# Preserve excel format using jxl API

Tags: java, jxl

I am using JXL to copy from one excel sheet to another.
When the data is getting copied to a new cell, it loses the actual formatting.

Eg. The large cells are converted to smaller ones in the new excel file.

Can someone please let me know if this is possible.

Regards

Bipul

Answer (score 1):

You should copy not only cell, but it's format too.

```
   oldCellFormat = oldCell.getCellFormat();
   newCellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(oldCellFormat );
   newCell.setCellFormat(newCellFormat);
```